# Why HI isn't fully miscible with cold water when HF is?

Tags: acid-base, solubility, hydrogen-bond

HF is more soluble in water than HI, due to greater hydrogen bonding in HF, accepted, but on the other hand HF is a weak acid so it's dissociation will be meagre when compared to HI's dissociation, so why is HF and not HI more soluble, am I misinterpreting the concept of solubility?

Comment: If you know what solubility is, I wonder how you'd suppose to misinterpret it. Also your assumptions about HF are wrong  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34818/why-is-hf-the-least-acidic-hydrogen-halide

Comment: I still could not understand , what I was able to gather from that link is , HF does dissociate but due to high electronegativity diff. thr H+ is not freed resulting in low acid strength , am I right?

Comment: This is not off-topic, the author gives a very clear attempt to understand the underlying principles.

Comment: @NutanPrakash Pretty much this. BTW your question may be better worded as why HI isn't fully miscible with cold water when HF is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hydrogen iodide is not listed as miscible with water because it is a gas. Miscibility is a property generally ascribed to pairs of liquids. Hydrogen fluoride is a liquid, and so it can be described as miscible with water. HF is a weak acid, but its high solubility can be explained by the high polarity of the H-F bond and the ability of HF to be both a hydrogen bond donor and accepter.

Hydrogen iodide is a gas at room temperature. It's boiling point is $-35\ ^\circ\text{C}$. Just because it is not miscible does not mean that it is not highly soluble. The solubility of HI in water is 245 g per 100 mL. In other words, a saturated solution has more HI by mass than water. HI is a strong acid, and the solubility of the gas is due to the nearly complete ionization of HI. Since HI is a gas, I presume that the solubility limit occurs when the vapor pressure of HI above the solution is high enough that vaporization begins to compete with ionization.

Physical data on HI from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_iodide)

Comment: that means solubility can be attributed to both - high polarity and complete ionization in particular cases.And I chose HI just because I wanted to compare solubilities of species which dissolve due to complete ionization - like strong acids and HF due to hydrogen bonding .

Comment: HF is a liquid *if your lab is relatively cold* (bp ~19 °C). Anyway, the main point is that solubility and ionisation are not strongly related.