# Why does HF generate a carbocation with an alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I was reading of different ways to perform Friedel Craft alkylations.

One of the methods I came across involved an alkene in the presence of H+ or a mineral acid like $\ce{HF}$. Here $\ce{H+}$ or $\ce{HF}$ caused an electromeric shift of the pi electrons and the $\ce{H+}$ bonded there resulting in a carbocation.

However I felt like the bond strength of $\ce{HF}$ is so high that it couldn't be possible to cleave it for the donation of $\ce{H+}$ (If that's what happens. Correct me if I'm wrong).

Why does it still generate a carbocation?

Comment: Well, it sure can do that if it's concentrated enough. Somewhat depending on alkene and temperature, though, I guess.

Comment: You felt wrong. HF is a typical acid, behaves like an acid, and (most likely) tastes like an acid.

Comment: @IvanNeretin But HF is a really weak acid, owing to its extremely strong bond with hydrogen

Comment: @Mithoron But what could cause the HF bond cleavage? Surely the pi electrons wouldnt suffice?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34818/is-hf-the-least-acidic-hydrogen-halide/34829#34829

Comment: It's neither truly weak, nor typical. Diluted aq HF wouldn't do it, but pure could work wonders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However I felt like the bond strength of $\ce{HF}$ is so high that it couldn't be possible to cleave it for the donation of $\ce{H+}$

HF has the highest single bond energy and hence you were right in expecting that it may not dissociate.However in concentrated solutions, due to the formation of stable hydrogen bonded complex $\ce{[HF_2]-}$, the reaction is pushed in the forward direction making it  a resonably strong acid (in fact strongest among corresponding concentrated solutions of all the hydrogen halides).So, you could generate a carbocation with that.However, as generally dilute solutions are used which are economically feasible, more stronger mineral acids in dilute solutions  like $\ce{HCl, HBr}$ and $\ce{HI}$ are used.

EDIT:

As suggested by Oscar Lanzi in the comments, acids like $\ce{HCl, HBr}$ and $\ce{HI}$ are safer to handle when compared to $\ce{HF}$ as the reactions of $\ce{HF}$ are associated with highly negative enthalpy changes [highly exothermic]

Comment: Not just an economic advantage.  HF is more dangerous to work with than HCl or HI, especially if you need a strong acid and thus would have to concentrate the HF.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thanks for adding value.I will update my answer to include this as well.

Comment: Also more dangerous than HBr.  Left that out!