# Why does HCl act as a weak base in HF solvent, even though it is a stronger acid compared to HF?

Tags: acid-base, halides

I've read that $\ce{HCl}$ acts as a weak base in $\ce{HF}$ solvent, which means $\ce{HCl}$ is supposed to lose $\ce{H+}$ ion to $\ce{HF}$. $\ce{HF}$ is a weak acid compared to $\ce{HCl}$, then shouldn't $\ce{HF}$ be accepting the proton and HCl be losing it. Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrofluoric_acid

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34818/is-hf-the-least-acidic-hydrogen-halide

Answer (score 6):

As Poutnik hints in [his reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrofluoric_acid), it is not accurate to call $\ce{HF}$ a weak acid in water. What appears in dilute aqueous solution as a weak acid is the hydrogen-bonded ion pair $\ce{H3O^+F^-}$ that forms when $\ce{HF}$ reacts with water. If this ion pair is placed in concentrated $\ce{HF}$, it will act as a **strong** base, forming $\ce{H3O^+}$ and $\ce{FHF^-}$ where the latter is the characteristics basic species in $\ce{HF}$. Thus $\ce{HCl}$ is a stronger acid than the aqueous $\ce{H3O^+F^-}$ solute in water, and $\ce{HCl}$ is also less basic than $\ce{H3O^+F^-}$ in $\ce{HF}$.

The Hammett acidity function of neat $\ce{HF}$, unsullied by water, is close to that of 100% $\ce{H2SO4}$. So, anything with appreciable acidity in $\ce{HF}$ would cross over into superacidity. $\ce{HCl}$ does not make it.

Comment: Note that the Hammer function of liquid HF is comparable to the value of H2SO4.

Comment: So is the Hammett function.  Autocorrect got you maybe?

Comment: :-) Definitely.  Google knows better than you what  want to say. :-D